# Threejs saving object to json with animations

Tags: animation, three.js, save

I can successfully load a 3D object from, for example, an FBX File, load and play it's animations. The problem is that, after doing what i gotta do with it, i need to save the changes. To do that, I'm saving the object and the object animation clip to a JSON. I can, now, load the 3D Object in the scene, but no animations will play(it'll stand on T pose), but trying to load the saved clip on the object loaded from FBX will play the animation without a problem.

After reading the resulting JSON from the 3D Object, a lot of data seems to be missing, that's why trying to play animations does nothing.
How can i save the loaded FBX model to a .json and keep the important data? I remember seeing some post about putting some flags on the toJSON method, but couldn't find anything similar again.

Edit: 
Using GLTF seems to solve this problem, but three.js GLTFLoader isn't loading any kind of .gltf object and i don't know why, for all of the objects i've tried using (used objects from threejs.org GLTFExporter examples) i'm getting the same error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'geometry' of undefined
at GLTFLoader.js:2572
```

That's how i'm trying to load it:

```
    loader_helper.gltf_loader.load("./src/data/scene.gltf", function ( gltf ) {
        console.log(gltf); // This is enough to get the error, altough i've tried 
                           // mimicking the FBX import, but getting the same errors
    });
```

Edit: Using https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/ to view the object, the object i exported was completely bugged ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cm58Z.jpg ) and i didn't notice, but i tested the bugged object three times, so i thought the problem was in the loader, it is seems to be loading fine using a non-bugged object. Although the export is bugged, the object skinned mesh is loading without issues and only the mesh is being loaded with, wel.. you saw it. https://i.stack.imgur.com/04lGb.jpg

That's how i'm exporting the scene:

```
// this is a button.onclick function
var exporter = new THREE.GLTFExporter();

exporter.parse( that.scene, function(gltf){
    var stringfied = JSON.stringify(gltf, null, 3);
    require("fs").writeFile( "./src/data/scene.gltf", stringfied, 'utf8', function(err) {
        console.log(err); // saving it to file with nodejs file system
    });
    console.log(gltf);
} );
```

Comment: Serializing a `THREE.SkinnedMesh` is currently not supported. However, there is already a PR that should solve this issue (see https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/15413). Until a solution gets merged, I suggest you use the code from the PR.

Comment: THREE.GLTFExporter supports skinned meshes and animation. Note that you’ll have to pass the animations in with the export options.

Comment: @DonMcCurdy I'm using the GLTFExporter to save stuff, but GLTFLoader doesn't seem to load any object. I've tried using .gltf files exported from the threejs.org examples aswell as some i've created but all of  them gives the same errors. I've edited the OP with more details.

Comment: What version of threejs? The code above sounds a bit like a bug in r102, but I'd need a demo or enough code to fully reproduce this to debug further. To save time and see if the models you're exporting are valid at all, try loading them in http://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/

Comment: @DonMcCurdy It seems that i'm exporting it wrong, or the exporter is bugged(doubt that). Somehow i didn't notice yesterday but i ended up testing the import with the same object three times(my bad...) so i thought it was throwing this error always.
The exported file is completely fucked up https://imgur.com/a/yLimuWp
I've edited the OP to show how i'm exporting. PS: If that info is useful for you, loader_helper is just a bunch of different loaders with their loading functions.